# Comment Display

Tags: 8, comments

How can I change the way that comments are displayed on my Drupal 8 page?

I can modify the display of some of the fields at

```
/admin/structure/comment/manage/comment/display
```

but this allows for rather limited changes only, e.g. doesn't allow changes to titles and links.

I can create my own [view](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views) to get a custom layout for the comments, but currently ctools, layout_plugin, and page manager for Drupal 8 are still an alpha release, and therefore I can't attach the view as a panel to my node.

Anyone got any ideas how to solve this? Where could I modify the display of my comments programmatically?

Comment: I see you have already answered your question and it is a valid solution.
However, would you elaborate and say what exactly you would like to modify ? Maybe there will be another way to achieve the same goal, without  modifying the templates.

Comment: I wanted to have the title displayed in a different size (h3 rather than h2), and have author name and creation date on separate lines below the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take /core/modules/comment/templates/comment.html.twig file from your Drupal installation directory and place it in the directory of the theme that you are using in the *templates* folder, for example /themes/bootstrap/templates/. Modify that file to change the way your comments are displayed. You might have to clear the cache to see your changes.

It may be worth creating a sub theme first, so that you don't loose your changes when you update the theme.